# Prove $(x,p)$ is maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have seen similar questions and their proof but I wanted to try to prove it using simpler proofs.
Like when we proved that $(x,2)$ is maximal ideal using $f(x)=x*p(x)+a_0$ and then dividing to options when $a_0$ is even or odd.
I tried to prove it in a similar way to the $(x,2)$ proof but I'm stuck.
**My try :**
Assume $(x,p)$ is not maximal ideal ($p$ is prime) which means - exists maximal ideal $M$ such that
$(x,p)\subset M \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$
By the assumption - $\exists f(x)\in M$ such that $p(x) \notin (x,p)$
$$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$$
$$f(x)=x(a_nx^{n-1}+a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+...+a_1)+a_0$$
Now if $a_0 =0$ then $f(x) \in (x,p)$.
if $p$ is in the prime factorization of $a_0$ then again $p(x)\in (x,p)$
if $p$ is not in the prime factorization of $a_0=q*..$ such that $q$ is prime.
and here I'm stuck -
it means that $M$ has element of the type $(x,p,q)$ but I wasn't able to prove $1\in M$ or something ($1\in M$ in the case when $p=3$ and $q=2$ for example).

Is there even a way to prove in this way? Any hint would help.
Have a nice day and thank you in advance.

Comment: You see to love computations… It is much simpler to use the 3rd isomorphism theorem to check the quotient is a field.

Comment: What is the quotient isomorphic to?

Comment: @Bernard I really do haha :)

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph: The quotient is the field $\mathbf F_p$.

Comment: In last step if $a_o$ hadn't divisible by p then why he will only be prime ? E.g. you can start with ideal gernated by ( 2 , X ) then $a_o$ can be 15 so that it's not gernated by 2. So q is set of collection of all numbers whose not divisible by p. So i don't know how much i am right but p+1 isn't divisible by p ( except the trivial case that starting ideal exhibit 1 ).  So 1 is there .

Comment: You are using $p$ for two different things: an integer $p$ (I suppose you mean a *prime* integer, but you never say so) and a polynomial. Please revise your question and then think of Bernard's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of computing explicitly with ideals and showing that you cannot have an ideal between $(x,p)$ and ${\mathbb Z}[x]$, it is much easier to compute the quotient ring.

Since an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is maximal if and only if $R/I$ is a field, another approach is to compute ${\mathbb Z}[x]/(x,p)$ and see that it is a field.

(For what it's worth, the quotient is ${\mathbb F}_p$, the finite field of $p$ elements.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, that is what I did in the end - I understood that every coset in $R/(x,p)$ is of the form $t+(x,p)$ such that $t\in \mathbb{Z}_p$. as known $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field so $R/(x,p)$ is a field $\Rightarrow (x,p)$ maximal ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The following result is often used to prove that $I$ is a maximal ideal of a ring $R$:

`An ideal I of a ring R is maximal if and only if R/I is a field.`

**Claim:** $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p,x) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, which is a field, and thus $(p,x)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

**Proof:** Define $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ by evaluation at $0$ modulo $p$, or

$$f(x) \mapsto f(0)(mod \;p)$$

It is easy to check that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism. All that remains is to show that $\phi$ is surjective and $ker \;\phi = (x, p)$.

As $\mathbb{Z}$ is embedded in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as the constant polynomials, any element $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the image of $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Hence, the map is surjective.

Further, $$ker \; \phi = \{f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]: f(0) = 0(mod\; p)\}$$
That is, the kernel consists of the functions $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ whose constant term is divisible by $p$.
Clearly, $$g_1(x)\cdot x+ g_2(x) \cdot p \in ker \; \phi, \; for \;g_1, g_2 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$$
$$\implies (x, p) \subseteq ker \; \phi$$

Now to show the other inclusion, let $f(x) \in ker\; \phi$. As $x$ is monic, we can divide $f(x)$ by $x$. This means that there exists $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that:
$$f = q(x)\cdot x + r(x),$$ where $r=0$ or $deg (r) < 1$. This means that $r(x)$ is essentially a constant, say $r$.

As $f \in ker\; \phi$, we have $$f(0) = 0 (mod \;p)\implies r = 0(mod\;p).$$
This means that $r$ is divisible by $p$, or $r = ps$ for some $s \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Finally, notice that $$f(x) = q(x)\cdot x + p\cdot s$$
$$\therefore f(x) \in (x, p)$$
$$\implies ker\; \phi \subseteq (x, p)$$

Thus, we have that $ker\; \phi = (x, p)$. By the first isomorphism theorem, we have $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x, p)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so $(x, p)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, as $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field for prime $p$. $\;\blacksquare$